# "cat: write error: No space left on device" when I write to a character device using "cat"

Tags: linux-device-driver, space, cat, device-driver, inode

I am trying to use VS1053, an audio decoder, on Linux 4.14 to play music. This device communicate through SPI bus, and I've developed a driver and registered VS1053 as a character device, thanks for https://github.com/rvp-nl/vs10xx-linux. Here comes the problem.

The way to play music is:

```
cat musicfile.mp3 > /dev/VS1053_device
```

When I throw a WAV music file to the device, everything is ok, and music plays well. However, when I throw a mp3 music file to the device, Linux casts an error

> cat: write error: No space left on device

I've searched for the reason on many sites. Many said, check free space and free inode on file system, but this is my result:

```
root@s32v234sbc:~# df -i                                                        
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on                             
/dev/root      956592 10795 945797    2% /                                      
devtmpfs       234285   308 233977    1% /dev                                   
tmpfs          234333   205 234128    1% /run                                   
tmpfs          234333    10 234323    1% /var/volatile                          
root@s32v234sbc:~# df -h                                                        
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on                                
/dev/root        15G  412M   14G   3% /                                         
devtmpfs        916M     0  916M   0% /dev                                      
tmpfs           916M   84K  916M   1% /run                                      
tmpfs           916M   28K  916M   1% /var/volatile                             
root@s32v234sbc:~#
```

The music file is limited within 100MB, there is no way that the space is used up.

I tried to write an print file program to substitute "cat", but that doesn't work either. I have no idea why and how this error happened.

I am super grateful if anyone could help me on this!!!

Comment: What is the output of the command `ls -l /dev/VS1053_device`? Looking at the code, I think the device pathname should be something like "/dev/vs10xx-0".

Comment: @Ian Abbott Output of your command is: crw------- 1 root root 245, 0. You are right on the name, my "VS1053_device" is the "vs10xx-0". I modified the name only.

Comment: Sorry, but on Stack Overflow we want the problematic code to be in the **question post** itself, not linked. Also, we expect from you to perform some **debugging**, so resulted code should be in the form of [mcve]. You may insert some `printk` statements into `vs10xx_write` function to find out why it returns `ENOSPC`. If this is the value returned by some kernel function, then ask about that function.

Answer (score 0):

try the below command:

```
 tune2fs -l /dev/VS1053_device | grep -i reserved
```

And cat is not suitable for the operation you are performing.The MP3 format has all sorts of junk that can lurk at the front and end of the file and this needs to be strippe out.Try with ***ffmpeg or mp3wrap or aplay***

Comment: Actually, I think "/dev/VS1053_device" is a character special device, not an extN filesystem. That is if the pathname is actually correct, which I doubt. Also, according to its documentation, it seems that this device _can_ handle MP3 data streams written to it, in addition to WAV, OGG, AAC and FLAC.

Comment: @Gopika BG  tune2fs gives me "Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock". I can use ffmpeg to convert mp3 file into wav. As I said, wav music file plays well. I don't have mp3wrap nor aplay on my Linux.

Comment: @ lan Abbott This device can handle multiple music data format internally. I just need to push the data streams to it. I also wrote a driver for this device on STM32 without any OS, and mp3 file has been proved ok to play.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a problem with the driver you are using. When you get "no space left on device" it doesn't mean in this case that the local filesystem is full. Probably it means that there is some problem on local or the other side of the SPI bus. It is possible that the driver you are using receives -ENOSPC status from SPI driver from linux kernel, but your driver doesn't service this error properly. So it will be needed to dig a little into the driver you are using.

Comment: You are absolutely right that it has something to do with my driver, but I don't know where could cause this problem. When debugging, I noticed a very weird case. In vs10xx_queue.c, I modified the variable queuelen from 256 to 8192. When I increased queuelen, I could not even play some wav file. I believe data format is also a reason, but I don't have a way to debug on this problem.

Comment: I think you could check where did you get the -ENOSPC status from. There is the function vs10xx_write() in sources and you could start from analyzing it. From this function another one is called: vs10xx_device_write() and I think you could follow this path and go further and try to find out where -ENOSPC occurs. I suspect that this status can occur somewhere in SPI layer of linux kernel.

Comment: The strange thing is, there doesn't seem to be anywhere in the write path that returns `-ENOSPC`. Increasing the `queuelen` variable should only affect whether the driver successfully creates the device or not (due to running out of memory).

Comment: @Gerald: Which version of the driver from git do you use? Is this exactly this one from the github or another one? I'd try to debug vs10xx_write() proc and log values of "status" and "copied" variables while trying to recreate the problematic situation - before "return" in this proc.

Comment: @user2699113 The link I posted is the version I use. I think your idea is probably right, the error is very likely occurring in kernel. I'm gonna analyze into vs10xx_write(). Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @IanAbbott queuelen defines the length of the buffer to hold data. From this strange result, I suspect that the difference between the rate I cast an file into the driver and the rate it reads those file data could be one problem.

Comment: It looks like `vs10xx_write` can return 0 if there are no free buffers. I guess something in user space is turning that into an `ENOSPC` error. The main problem is that the "vs10xx" driver doesn't handle blocking or non-blocking writes properly.